# Can not build an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, junit

I have a simple test class using junit. Unfortunatlly, it complains when i want to run the test case.

Here is the maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and then in the test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RestUploaderApplication.class)
public class RestUploaderApplicationTests {

    Station station1;
    Station station2;
    Content content1;
    Content content2;

    ContentRepository contentRepo;
    StationRepository stationRepo;

    @Before
    public void createObjects(){
        Station station1=new Station("UT","Livii 2");
        Station station2=new Station("City Center","Kissing Square");
        Content content1=new Content(station1,"BMW","Text","google.com",10,true);
        Content content2=new Content(station2,"SWB","Image","swb.com",100,true);

    }

    @Test
    public void insertInstancesTest() {
        int size=station1.getContents().size();
        assertEquals(1,size);
    }}
```

and finally, in the runtime the error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@67b64c45] to prepare test instance  a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` was deprecated in spring boot 1.4.0.

I'm not sure but could try replacing `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` with `@SpringBootTest` eg

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RestUploaderApplicationTests {
```

`SpringBootTest` should automatically configure your spring context loader (while hopefully resloves the error: **...instance  a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration**) and also automatically configures your `MockMVC` (although it appears you do not need in this case)

As an aside, if that is the actual test plan, it does't look like it needs to be Spring aware, there doesn't seem to be any spring components used, (@Beans / @MockBeans, @Autowired, @Controllers, etc) and regular old JUnit should be just fine

Hope this helps

EDIT // Added sources

[@SpringApplicationConfiguration docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.4.x-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html)

[@SpringBootTest docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.4.x-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html)